# Unicode characters are not being rendered anymore, what happened?

Tags: unicode, input-encodings, linux, bugs

I used to be able to render Unicode characters without any issues in LaTeX. However, since a couple days (I noticed) TeXstudio is not rendering them anymore...

If I use:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
    Möbius
\end{document}
```

Then after compiling just *Mbius* appears.

I guess something has been changed since it used to be working, could anyone point me into the right direction? What could I check?

I'm using Elementary OS Loki. I've checked if any packages got updated recently, but no new texlive packages got installed/upgraded recently.

#### Edit

I wanted to post the compilation log and noticed I'm compiling through XeTeX now instead of LaTeX. Apparently XeTeX needs extra packages to be able to compilte unicode characters?
`\usepackage{polyglossia}` seems to resolve the issue...

Comment: Exactly what encoding is the file stored in? And are there any warnings in the log?

Comment: I think the issue is fixed, apparently the default compilation engine was set to XeTeX, and for some reason XeTeX needs extra packages (?). Thanks for the help though :)

Comment: Xelatex should work out of the box with utf8 contents, but should not be used with inputenc

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP mentioned that it's fixed in the comments.

Comment: Should I remove it myself?

Comment: @TeXnician although that isn't really a fix.

Comment: @daleif not with older latex releases as it will be using 7bit cmr so the accent won't work..

Comment: @DavidCarlisle that was what I was thinking as well as the op I probably using latex from the Linux dist, and we usually know better ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you presumably have an old copy of latex, with a 2017  release,  xelatex would default to TU (Unicode) with an older release it will default to the 7bit OT1 encoding (and your log file will have missing character warnings)

`polyglossia` is not directly involved other that it will load the `fontspec` package which will force the encoding to Unicode (TU or the older EU2 encoding)

So with a current latex release your original document would work (although you should not use `inputenc` with xelatex, it does nothing other than give a warning) with an older xelatex then you need to add  `\usepackage{fontspec}`

Comment: This was probably the issue, according to apt I have version `(2015.20160320-1)`. I guess an update would be in order ;)